How to stop Firefox mobile from automatically load a clicked link?
When you click a link in many apps, the URL already comes with all sorts of info about your device, and since I'm a little too conscious about that, I would like to inspect each URL before Firefox sends that request for god knows where, but click super fast in the X button seems too crude (and probably ineffective) for me.
Is there something in about:config or somewhere else for that?

I kind of doubt if there's an option in about:config to prevent automatically loading a URL/site (it might be annoying sooner or later while browsing normally). On the other hand, I heard Firefox for Android supports browser extensions, so perhaps there's something for this (I don't know any though). Otherwise, if this is specifically for links outside from Firefox, then perhaps an intent interceptor app might work (I don't know any though)

An interceptor app might be a feasible choice, but it would bring it own set of concerns.
But in the firefox extensions side, they are quite limited in number because the people from mozilla seems to checks them thoroughly (something i'm thankful for)
